# Megento2 Sorting Issue using custom attributes

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, sorting

I have a website created with magento 2 and it is working perfectly.

After adding a bunch of products, We've encountered some issues with it's sorting. Sorting is not working properly most times.

For example sorting with custom attribute **product Net Weight**, which results in First five or six with proper value (11,12,13,14) after that it shows (100,102,105 etc).

Then again it shows lower values. I have not yet done any changes to the core function.

Here is the link to the site [Link to the category with net weight sorting](https://www.chungathjewellery.com/gold/necklace?product_list_order=net_weight)

I think you guys can help me with it.

Comment: Do reindex by this command: `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Comment: @PrincePatel i did it many times. But no changes found

Answer (score 1):

To set the custom attributes for sorting in listing page. Kindly go to the `admin Stores->Configuration->Catalog->Catalog->Product Listing Sort by-> set your custom attributes`.

Now it is working fine.